# Gluing along infinitely many trivial cofibrations

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories

I am in a situation where I have a space Y obtained from a space X by gluing on infinitely many trivial cells. That is, I have a collection of maps

$f_\alpha: A_\alpha \to X$

each of which is a cofibration. I also have weak equivalences

$g_\alpha: A_\alpha \to B_\alpha$.

And I know that $Y$ is obtained as the pushout of

$\coprod_\alpha B_\alpha \leftarrow \coprod_\alpha A_\alpha \to X$.

Now, I know that a pushout of a weak equivalence along a cofibration is again a weak equivalence. But here, while each map $f_\alpha$ is a cofibration, the coproduct $\coprod_\alpha f_\alpha$ is not a cofibration (the images overlap, for instance).

It seems like the induced map $X \to Y$ should still be a weak equivalence. How do I prove this?

Comment: The description in the first paragraph doesn't fit well with the actual situation – I would have expected the cells to be cofibrations, not the attaching maps.